# ListBox Item style

Tags: wpf

I need to write a style for a listboxItem that will add a button on the right of the listboxitem when it is selected or mouse over. The button need to have a command binding as well . 
This style need to be used in different places.
also the button won't have a border. but when the mouse is over the button , it will have a border.

How can i write this?

I tried to write a style, but i can't bind to the command of the button that is inside the style.

Code used: (sorry i wasn't able to paste my code normally here so it is here http://justpaste.it/1b9s)

Comment: Can we see the code you've used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great to see some code but an option that should work is to create a DataTemplate. You can set it on ListBox ItemTemplate property and use it in the different locations where you may need it.

Comment: right , but the problem with ItemTemplate is that when mouse is moving to fast between the ListBoxItems, the button is visible in many items, which are not selected and not mouse over